# FullCalendar event on mouseover gives jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, fullcalendar

In under the Week-view, on event `mouseOver` I receive this error message in firebug:

> `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ,
>
>   throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
>
>   jquery-1.8.3.js (line 4680)`

has anyone encountered such a problem, or is there a way to debug to origins of the error?

Thanks in advance
Sincerely

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the tags `jQuery` and `JavaScript` when having javascript problems ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by jQuery-Mobile. FullCalendar could not function properly in jQuery-Mobile environment. After going back to jQuery-UI everything worked fine again.

Thanks for your effort to help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a selector bug:

```
$("abc, def, "); // or
$("<div,");
```

Is not sure.

If you look in the source code for jQuery 1.8.3 you will find these lines around line 4680:

```
/*LINE: 4679*/ Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
/*LINE: 4680*/     throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
/*LINE: 4681*/ };
```

It's hard to debug your code from here but you could try to put `arguments.callee.caller` right before `throw new Error`:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    console.log( arguments.callee.caller );
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

That will tell you what function is calling this function. From there you can try to travel up using the same method. At the end you will find your problem.

---

**What is `arguments.callee.caller`**?

`arguments` is an array like property containing all the arguments parsed to a function:

```
function a() {}
a(1, 2, 3); // Inside a arguments will be: [1, 2, 3]
```

`arguments` have a property called `callee` this property contains a reference to the function called eg. it self:

```
function a() {} // arguments.callee === a.
```

`arguments.callee` have a  non standard (but standard, just not described in ECMA) property called `caller` this property contains a reference to the function who is calling it on runtime.

```
function a() {
    b()
}
function b() {}; // arguments.callee.caller === a;

a();
```

And some docs:

- [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)
- [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)
- [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)

Do you know about the `console`-object?

Comment: Hi, is the the bug on my side? I don't know why it works under the month view without problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your knowledge is over my head. I'll give it a try first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by going away from jQuery-Mobile and back to jQuery-UI only.
FullCalendar doesn't work properly under jQuery-Mobile.